# HP Hard drive swap problems

Tags: windows

I have two computers:

1. a HP pavilion dm4-3050 laptop from a friend with a broken HDD,
2. a HP g62 with a working HDD. It is an old system which I no longer use.

Both systems originally ran windows 7.

I want to use the laptop from the old drive into the other laptop.

I switched the drive but windows fails to boot in the completely different hardware. I tried safemode, recovery disks etc but I cannot get windows to work.

Do I just need To go ahead and buy the full disk set and install that way. All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?  You cannot simply swap an HDD with an installed Windows to another PC.  That violates the license, besides the fact that it typically won't boot as you have already found out.

Comment: @sawdust Really? That violates the license? It isn't like the OP is trying to copy the HDD and give it to someone else. I don't see any difference between that and fresh installing on a new computer with the product key of a computer whose HDD died.

Comment: @BenjiWiebe Yes, it violates the license. OP could do a fresh install with the dm4's license and be OK for Microsoft. Different CPUs, chassis, etc can have different license terms and fees. If you want to argue, do so with Microsoft - it's their terms.

Comment: @Stacy If you want to copy the data, you can copy that from drive to drive.

Comment: @mpez0 So it is illegal to upgrade CPU's?!

Comment: Before you remove the HDD from the donor PC, you would need to run [`sysprep /generalize`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721940%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).  You should probably backup all data that you want to preserve just in case the reinstall overwrites anything.

Comment: @sawdust... That's the only problem my old laptop can't power up the cord broke so I won't be able to sysprep it

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the DM4 starts to boot windows with all drivers and settings configured for ther G62. As you have discovered, this usually does not work.

What you want to do is either:

1. Put the disk back in the old system. Uninstall as much laptop specific tools as possible. Then run sysprep to tell windows to delete as many drivers as possible and to detect and reconfigure on the next start. After shut down move the disk to the new system and boot it.
2. Or install a clean version of windows. You already had win7 on the laptop. All you need is either a HP OEM win7 installation CD of a matching version (if it had win 7 home you need a home disk, if it had pro you need a pro disk, etc etc) or another legal windows 7 disk and the matching CoA.